# Tag Management Request: [google-sketchup] -> [sketchup]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[Google SketchUp has been purchased by Trimble](http://sketchup.google.com/), and is no longer a product of Google. Therefore, I recommend:

- Renaming [google-sketchup](/questions/tagged/google-sketchup) to [sketchup](/questions/tagged/sketchup) and making [trimble-sketchup](/questions/tagged/trimble-sketchup) a synonym, or perhaps
- Creating [sketchup](/questions/tagged/sketchup) and making both [google-sketchup](/questions/tagged/google-sketchup) and [trimble-sketchup](/questions/tagged/trimble-sketchup) synonyms.

Comment: No one wants to update this tag? It's getting close to a year since it was sold.

Comment: Concrete suggestion: retag [tag:google-sketchup] to [tag:sketchup] and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

It's now been a year since SketchUp was bought up by Trimble. It'd be nice to see this tag corrected.

However, I do think that the most appropriate tag would be `sketchup` as prefixing it with the parent company makes the tag prone to more changes. Also, one could then also argue there should be an `@last-sketchup` tag as that was the original company name.

But I really would prefer to avoid prefixing with company name? I mean, `apple-osx`, `microsoft-windows`? It's not as though there are any other product called SketchUp.