# Tag Management Request?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

[What's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136779/tag-management-request-task-tasks) [with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136769/tag-management-request-sudoers-sudo) [all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136747/tag-management-request-google-sketchup-sketchup) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136759/tag-management-request-widget-widgets) `Tag Management Request` titles?

Did I miss the memo about this being required. Is this mandatory now for retag / synonym requests? Is this something someone thought was useful? Something else?

Comment: Some people don't have enough reputation in the given tags to suggest synonyms, especially if there are very close tags involved (ex. widget/widgets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created 12 such questions (all except 1) last 24 hours. I'm done now. (Added `ignored tags`, that's why I find them). The `Tag Management Request` titles is because I have to vary myself. If I create more type `Merge [smooth] ⇒ [smoothing]` titles. Then the system would not accept my question. Error message, `this question have already been asked`.

Comment: Aha. Didn't see it was all you. Just looked at the first couple I find and some another nick. So what you are saying is that the filter is crewing things up?

Comment: Yes, creating my filter makes me find them. (Sure I don't want to read questions with strange general tags like `merge validation hardware values editor post remove text`)

Comment: I have now merged 3 questions (pluralization 's) to one. Feel free to vote on it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136759 since nobody does.